# can't send data from android to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to develop android applications. I need to store ID in in WAMP server. When I try to run my code, emulator shows "Unfortunately myapp has stopped" message and I can't send data from android to PHP.

I am trying to fix this for past two days. I added my activity to the manifest file.
Here is my .java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputid;

    private static String url_sample = "http://localhost/android_connect/sample.php";
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Edit Text
        inputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new add().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class add extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
      /**
       * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
       * */
       @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("your Registration is processing..wait for few sec..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String id = inputid.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sample, "POST", params);
            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    setResult(100,i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return doInBackground();
        }

       /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

PHP code is:

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $userid = $_POST['id'];
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO id(ID) VALUES('$userid')");
    echo $userid;
    if ($result) 
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = " Registered successfully";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else 
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else 
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

no error in both PHP and Android coding..logcat shows error messages..some are

```
04-09 17:06:02.552: I/Choreographer(10719): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Try to remplace localhost with 10.0.2.2

Comment: there should be something in the stacktrace if it is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error message because of the line

```
    return doInBackground();
```

you are calling the doInBackground() method recursively, which gives the thread heavy work load.

try to return some string (in your case, just return null;)

Comment: got it.. if you are using localhost, then you should call the url like this  "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/sample.php"

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be calling your code recursively, in `doInBackground(...)` you are once again calling `doInBackground`, and also without arguments (probably gives you a `NoSuchMethodException`), according to your specification you must return a string, but seeing as you are not using the result you might as well return a null (or change the specification to `Void`).

Also, the reason that you are not seeing the stacktrace is that you are probably filtering for `log` statements, whilst e.`printStackTrace()` does not use log statements.

**Edit:**
Please use
`Log.e("MyActivityNameHere", e.toString())` instead of `e.prinStackTrace()` to see the exception

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost, then you should call the url like this

```
      private static String url_sample = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/sample.php";
```